# Securing REST API across environments

Tags: mule

I have a REST API developed using Mule. It is deployed on prem Test and SystemTest environments. I can see that using Postman we can hit both test, systemtest API.

How do I make sure only applications can consume the API in the appropriate environments. There are system userids for each environments(C-users) and passwords which can be given to application consumers. The credentials need to be validated with Active directory LDAP Server.

How can we achieve this via Mule ESB?

For ex: application a1 running in Test should be able to consume only the API running in TEST. Application a1 running in Test should be able to consume only the API running in TEST.

Answer (score 0):

Vinay,

I assume that the option of having multiple environments is not achievable.
Do you have access to Anypoint Platform? If you do, you can register your API there and generate a client id per environment.

Then you can apply Client ID Enforcement policy.